# Print Full Tensor Value in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to print full tensor value (not truncated) in console but getting following exception:

```
 TypeError: Expected int for argument 'summarize' not <tf.Tensor
 'Size:0' shape=() dtype=int32>.
```

My code is as follows:

```
t = mask[0]
tf.Print(t,data = [t], summarize=tf.size(t))
```

Please note that there is old installation of tensorflow on server, so I cannot use newer tf.print function.

Comment: Would you reveal the tensorflow version you are using then?

Comment: `tf.size` returns a `Tensor`. That function expects an int. You may want to use `t.shape` instead.

Comment: @DocDriven unfortunately, I am not able to get tensorflow version as GPU on the server is occupied by some other people now. However, newer version tf.print is not supported there.

Comment: Tensorflow version is 1.11.0.

Comment: Also, can you post minimal, running example? Without knowing what you assign to ``t``, we can only guess here.